# launch move_base : error loading <rosparam> tag

Tags: navigation, move-base, rosparam, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,
i'm trying to launch move_base backage  and i used this launch file  :

```
<launch>
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find flo_navigation_rviz)/maps/couloir_hopi.yaml" output="screen"/>

<include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" > </include>
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" >
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find flo_navigation_rviz)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml"  />
<rosparam file="$(find flo_navigation_rviz)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find flo_navigation_rviz)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load"/>
<rosparam file="$(find flo_navigation_rviz)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find flo_navigation_rviz)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
</node>
</launch>
```

i get this error  :

```
error loading <rosparam> tag: 
    file does not exist [/home/kesuke-pc/catkin_ws/src/flo_navigation_rviz/param/costmap_common_params.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find flo_navigation_rviz)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" ns="global_costmap"/>
```

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

i put "costmap_common_params.yaml" in the folder named "param"   i dont understand  why rosparam can't find it ??
thanks in advance for all your  answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287342/launch-move_base--:-error-loading-%3Crosparam%3E-tag/) by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2018-04-03**:
Have you "sourced" your workspace when you opened a new terminal/tab?

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-04-03**:
thankks for asnwering yes i did

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2018-04-03**:
Sorry, but I have no idea why roslaunch can't find your file... Maybe is a silly question, but, is the whole path correct?

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-04-03**:
roscd find it so i don't think there is a problem with the path

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2018-04-03**:
Just to be sure, try:

```
gedit <the-whole-path-to-the-file>/<file-name>.yaml
```

Does it find it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-03**:
Please review the [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do_Not), specifically the *Do Not* section:

> DO NOT post a screenshot of the terminal or source file

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2018-04-03**:
Good!!!! Remember to set the post as solved!

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-04-03**:
gvdhoorn thank you for updating the post  i'm new in ROS i'm sorry i did not repsect all the rules

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-03**:
No problem. Keep it in mind for your next question.

Note also: this is in general an Askbot thing I believe. Not necessarily ROS specific. Images cannot be searched for text fi, which makes your question harder to find by search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Chaos you were right i dont why but it's doesn't diplay anything so i remove al the folder named 'param' and add new folder with the same name and i'ts works but i'm still dont understand what's was wrong
thank you for your answer

---

Originally posted by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) with karma: 58 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0